# how whereBetween handle to this query

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to use whereBetween to handle this query

```
select * from schedules where now() BETWEEN start and end
```

thank for your attentions

Answer (score 0):

You can write this query as:

```
$schedules = DB::table('schedules ')->select( 'id','name')
             ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '>=', 'startDateField' )
             ->where( DB::raw('now()'), '<=', 'endDateField' )
             ->get();
```

Also as per comment by @Devon, you can use `whereBetween`:

```
$schedules = DB::table('schedules ')->select( 'id','name')
             ->whereBetween( DB::raw('now()'), array('startDateField', 'endDateField')
             ->get();
```

Comment: whereBetween is probably better

Comment: sorry, end and start are the fields of schedule table

Comment: You can simply put your fields names in place of variables, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$schedules = DB::table('schedule')->select('id', 'name')
               ->whereBetween( DB::raw('now()'), [$startDate, $endDate])
               ->get();
```